# Why is my FireFox text not anti-aliased?

Tags: windows-vista, firefox

In Firefox my chrome text isn't anti-aliased.

Is this due to Windows Vista's font settings?

Comment: What text? In the chrome or on the pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend checking [this HowToGeek article on ClearType](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/tune-your-cleartype-font-settings-in-windows-vista/) to tweak your settings and to make it the way you want it to be

> **Tune Your ClearType Font Settings in Windows Vista**
>
> Many people have expressed to me their
>   dislike of the default ClearType font
>   smoothing in Windows Vista, and asked
>   for a way to change the settings to
>   something better. You have a couple of
>   options here:
>
> - You can just Disable or Enable ClearType.  (Note that if you are
>     still using a CRT monitor, you should
>     not be using ClearType anyway.)
> - Install Microsoft’s ClearType Tuner PowerToy for XP (which works in Vista,
>     even if it says it doesn’t)

[image]